# how to set the maximum leiningen repl history count?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

lein repl's command history appears to top out at 500 commands.  Is there a way to increase this number or set it to unlimited?

Comment: I can't find any reference in the docs, or really even anything useful in leiningen's source. The most obvious place that this would be would be in `project.clj`, but it [isn't documented](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/d6cc4b21adb0fe081e0b6aebbe9a2d3c7672fdfc/sample.project.clj#L362), and again, there's no reference to history options in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leiningen either uses readline (via `rlwrap`) or [jline](https://github.com/jline/jline2) for its REPL input, defaulting to the latter.  Both of which would be what is responsible for saving history to file.  In either case, they could both be configured by configuring your `~/.inputrc` which configures readline input in general.  So if you want to configure your history count, try adding the following setting in your `~/.inputrc`

```
set history-size 1000
```

Note that I don't think the jline implementation respects all readline configuration in the `~/.inputrc`, but it should definitely respect `history-size`.